# Cannot select the right div with jquery, I keep selecting the previous div as well

Tags: jquery, image

So I have an incredibly simple page setup where you click a button and an image appears and when click the image it disappears. However, whenever I add a second instance of the button it effects the previous image too. Normally I'm good at troubleshooting this stuff, but I am completely stumped.

I would have thought that clicking each item in a class would only select the clicked item as that's what I remember happening in the past.

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.image').css({
    width: '100px',
    height: '100px'
  })
  $(this).fadeOut();
})

$('.image').click(function() {
  let x = $(this).index()
  $(this).css({
    width: '0px',
    height: '0px'
  })
  $(this).siblings('.button').fadeIn()
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

#container1 {
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
}

.button {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  transition-duration: 1.0s;
}

#container2 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 500px;
}

#image1 {
  background-image: url('../images/slide1.jpg');
}

#image2 {
  background-image: url('../images/1.jpg');
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Title</title>
  <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container" id="container1">
    <div class="button" id="button1">+
    </div>
    <div class="image" id="image1">
      <div>
      </div>



      <div class="container" id="container2">
        <div class="button" id="button2">+
        </div>
        <div class="image" id="image2">
          <div>
          </div>



          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom_behaviors.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you have html issues.  Your `.image` elements do not have a closing `</div>`.  It looks like you left the `/` off of the trailing `<div>`s?

Comment: God damn. Simplest mistake in the book. Thanks for seeing it!

Comment: Make your comment as an answer and I'll mark you as having solved it for me :)

Comment: Np.  I was super confused why the snippet wasn't formatting the html correctly before I was like....oooooooh, ^_^

Comment: Actually, rather than an answer, this should be closed as a typo